# Oracle: using "as of" clause with table aliases?

Tags: oracle, flashback

I can run this flashback query with no problem:

```
select x from a as of timestamp sysdate;
```

But if I use a table alias I get an error.

```
select foo.x from a foo as of timestamp sysdate;
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

How can I use "as of" with table aliases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table alias follows the "as of" clause.

```
select x from a as of timestamp sysdate foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

And as an extension if you are joining multiple tables you can join them from different times if you want (not sure why you would want but...)

```
select *
from a as of timestamp sysdate-1 foo
join b as of timestamp sysdate-2 fi on foo.name = fi.name;
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. That, while correct, isn't directly relevant to the question at hand. Answers should be kept as relevant as possible to the question. Answers that are only asides may cause confusion and pollute search results. As to "why you would want to": joining a table to itself is very common where entities of the same type relate to one another, for example puling back data from person records for an employee and their manager: `FROM person underling JOIN person manager ON manager.id = underling.managerId`.